# Why do trailing separators change the behavior of relative path conversions in Boost.Filesystem?

Tags: c++, boost-filesystem

Given the following code,

```cpp
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
fs::path parentPath("/home/user1/");
fs::path childPath("/home/user1/Downloads/Books");
std::cout << childPath.lexically_relative(parentPath) << '\n';
```

I expect the output to be `"Downloads/Books"`, but instead it is `"../Downloads/Books"`. If I change the `parentPath` to `"/home/user1"` (removing the trailing separator), I do get my expected output.

In my *real* code, the paths often times come in as strings from data. In my context, a trailing slash at the end is unintentional and should be ignored for the purposes of any logic. Basically, in my program `"/home/user1"` is identical to `"/home/user1/"`. However the logic of `boost::filesystem::path` doesn't reflect this assertion.

So my question is two fold:

1. Why does the trailing separator affect the behavior? I just can't quite understand why it steps up a directory with `".."` in this case.
2. How can I make `path` ignore or normalize trailing slashes globally in my program? For example, "sanitizing" my path strings before I construct `path` objects would be too much of a maintenance burden, so I need something more inherent if possible.

Here's a [live sample](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ht2RbxuTcj667D97) I've been using for testing.

Comment: Looks like [this might be a bug](https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem/issues/76).

Comment: There’s not going to be a way to “configure” a class to change its behavior—such a capability would surely lead to much worse maintainability problems (and would presumably interfere with threads via global state).  All you can do is wrap the class and all the non-member functions (itself quite expensive for maintenance) or use “factory” functions everywhere.

Comment: @DavisHerring What are you even talking about?

Comment: “How can I make `path` ignore or normalize trailing slashes globally[…]?”  That would involve setting some sort of compile-time or runtime option that would affect all code, including that in libraries, right?

Comment: @DavisHerring I see what you mean now. Yes, I think we all understand that, and it's implied in my question (e.g. "globally"). I think you're assuming maybe that I already know such a "global" option does not exist, but decided to ask anyway for some reason. If the option doesn't exist, it doesn't exist, we don't need to delve into reasons why/why not at that point. I am trying to keep the question simple. Anyway I identified it's a bug so my question doesn't have the answer I was looking for. However I'll keep it here for informational purposes as I'm sure others will run into this.

Comment: It could easily be the case that “globally” meant “all over *my* code”, and it’s all too common to want that without realizing the implications.  (When a question like “What’s the syntax for *x*?” comes up that has no answer, I feel like a comment is the right response.)  I’m glad if you’re aware of them, and in that case I’m sorry for supposing you might not be, but I’m not sure why you would then ask—I for one would studiously avoid such a “feature” if it did exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out shortly after posting this question that this is a bug, [reported here](https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem/issues/76). I thought initially that I may have been doing something wrong. Even though my question doesn't make much sense at this point, I didn't want to just delete it in case others run into the same issue.